# How to handle as a Tester if the website is kicking out the user for recreating the session?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, vulnerability

Suppose a website is logging out the user after some time to re-create the session and start using the website. As the security tester, how will you handle this situation? Isn't it frustrating? Yes! looking from a security perspective this is a nice mechanism, but if you are a penetration tester, how will you handle this, will you just simply get login again and again, or you will do something else to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burp has session handling functionality that allows you to make a request to check if your session is valid, and if it has expired then it will login again. You can find it in the Project Options > Sessions tab.

Official documentation is here: https://portswigger.net/support/configuring-burp-suites-session-handling-rules

Comment: Yeah, that helps. Thanks for answering :))